# How do I display result from mongodb into a particular div in an ejs file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I have the following code that enables me to fetch documents from mongodb and return the as a result.
I need to display this data into a certain div in my ejs file for a particular admin page.

```
// Admin
router.get("/admin", ensureAuthenticated, authRole("admin"), (req, res) => {
    User.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
            res.render("admin", { users: result, user: req.user });
        }
    });
});
```

In the console, I am well able to get `result` as an array of objects. I have tried to access `result` with ejs syntax as follows, but to no avail:

```
<div class="db_objects">
        <%= users.result %>
    </div>
```

Comment: You set `{ users: result, user: req.user }`, so why are you calling `<%= users.result %>` instead of `<%= users %>`?

Comment: Oh yes oversight there! I just changed it and it has solved my problem. Thank you Geshode!

Comment: No problem. I guess, you can delete the question then.